# Got Error: "Error code: SMS401" in Azure

Tags: .net, azure, cloud

I have get Error: "Error code: SMS401" in Azure when trying to get the free subscription. I think this may have something with the US sanctions or so; any help?

Comment: You can find a list of all the countries where Azure is commercially available here: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/faq/

Comment: I checked the list and Sudan is under US sanctions at that time, now the sanctions were lift & still Sudan is not there!!! I will call the US Embassy in Khartoum & see what happen...many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest you contact with Azure support. It is the best choice for you to get the detailed information. Here is the [support channel](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/support/options/). Please click "Having issues signing up for an account" like the following screenshot.

[image]

Comment: I think it is because of the US sanctions, will call the US Embassy in Khartoum & see how I can solve this. many thanks.